# MySQL Query Performance - Query/Schema/Indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Basically having some performance issues with queries, mainly to my largest table which holds call data.

The main query contains quite a few left joins & sub-selects, but in a scenario where I'm running a query where I expect back 1.3M calls to be returned, the query is just not doing it. Having to stop it at 7 minutes means there's definately a problem somewhere.

I've narrowed down the main query and tested the simplest sub-select join which is

```
SELECT
    DateStart,
    ID,
    NumbID,
    EffectiveFlag,
    OrigNumber
FROM calls
WHERE 
    DateStart <= '2013-12-31'
AND DateStart >= '2013-01-01'
AND CallLength >= '00:00:00' 
AND Direction = '1'
AND CustID IN (474,482,250,268,197,604,132,359,279,441,118,448,152,133,380,162,249,679,226,259,2450,2408,2451,2453,2439,2454,2444,2445,2452)
```

And even that query takes 4.5s - so when it's a sub-select in a query with other joins & sub-selected, I can imagine why the query as a whole is unusable.

The explain statement for the above query is

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                                                                         | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calls | range | idx_CustID,idx_DateStart,idx_CustID_DateStart,idx_CustID_TermNumber,idx_Direction                     | idx_CustID_DateStart | 7       | NULL | 1660009 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

The database schema of the calls table is

```
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| ID                | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| CustID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| CarrID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| TariID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| CarrierRef        | varchar(30) | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| NumbID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
| VlviID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| VcamID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| SomeID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| VlnsID            | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| NGNumber          | varchar(12) | NO   |     |                     |                |
| OrigNumber        | varchar(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| CLIRestrictedFlag | int(2)      | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| OrigLocality      | varchar(11) | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| OrigAreaCode      | varchar(11) | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| TermNumber        | varchar(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| BatchNumber       | varchar(10) | NO   | MUL |                     |                |
| DateStart         | date        | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00          |                |
| DateClear         | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00          |                |
| TimeStart         | time        | NO   |     | 00:00:00            |                |
| TimeClear         | time        | NO   |     | 00:00:00            |                |
| CallLength        | time        | NO   |     | 00:00:00            |                |
| RingLength        | time        | NO   |     | 00:00:00            |                |
| EffectiveFlag     | smallint(1) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| UnansweredFlag    | smallint(1) | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| EngagedFlag       | smallint(1) | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| RecID             | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
| CreatedUserID     | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0                   |                |
| CreatedDatetime   | datetime    | NO   | MUL | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| Direction         | int(1)      | NO   | MUL | NULL                |                |
+-------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
```

The indexes on the calls table are

```
+-------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name                  | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| calls |          0 | PRIMARY                   |            1 | ID              | A         |    23905312 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CustID                |            1 | CustID          | A         |        1685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_NumbID                |            1 | NumbID          | A         |       37765 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_OrigNumber            |            1 | OrigNumber      | A         |     5976328 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_OrigLocality          |            1 | OrigLocality    | A         |       45019 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_OrigAreaCode          |            1 | OrigAreaCode    | A         |         846 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_TermNumber            |            1 | TermNumber      | A         |      232090 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_DateStart             |            1 | DateStart       | A         |        4596 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_EffectiveFlag         |            1 | EffectiveFlag   | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_UnansweredFlag        |            1 | UnansweredFlag  | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_EngagedFlag           |            1 | UnansweredFlag  | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_TariID                |            1 | TariID          | A         |         110 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CustID_DateStart      |            1 | CustID          | A         |        1685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CustID_DateStart      |            2 | DateStart       | A         |      919435 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_NumbID_DateStart      |            1 | NumbID          | A         |       37765 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_NumbID_DateStart      |            2 | DateStart       | A         |     5976328 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_RecID                 |            1 | RecID           | A         |      288015 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CarrierRef            |            1 | CarrierRef      | A         |     7968437 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CustID_CallTermNumber |            1 | CustID          | A         |        1685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CustID_CallTermNumber |            2 | TermNumber      | A         |      246446 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CreatedDatetime       |            1 | CreatedDatetime | A         |      771139 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_Direction             |            1 | Direction       | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_VlviID                |            1 | VlviID          | A         |       50539 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_SomeID                |            1 | SomeID          | A         |          30 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_VcamID                |            1 | VcamID          | A         |          64 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_VlnsID                |            1 | VlnsID          | A         |         191 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_CarrID                |            1 | CarrID          | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| calls |          1 | idx_BatchNumber           |            1 | BatchNumber     | A         |      271651 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-------+------------+---------------------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
```

Something which I understand may be causing the performance, is the indexes on columns with a low cardinality. I know columns such as Direction which has a cardinality of 2 is actually probably worse of with an index in terms of performance, but that alone shouldn't be making the statement so slow.

In terms of the cardinality requirements to have a worthwhile index, is there a general cardinality percentage compared to total table records at which an index increases performance and when it reduces performance?

I understand that no one is going to be able to throw an answer at me that will change the query time from 4.5s to 0.01s, but any advice on either the query itself, the table schema, the indexes, or the hardware would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

@Sebas "could you please rerun the query AND explain plan without the part: AND CallLength >= '00:00:00' AND Direction = '1' please?"

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                                       | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calls | range | idx_CustID,idx_DateStart,idx_CustID_DateStart,idx_CustID_TermNumber | idx_CustID_DateStart | 7       | NULL | 724813 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: could you please rerun the query AND explain plan without the part: `AND CallLength >= '00:00:00' AND Direction = '1'` please?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the storage engine?

Comment: @DavidPope Storage engine is MyISAM

Comment: @stanyer does the query complete faster?

Answer (score 4):

Is your "DateStart" a truncated datetime -- keep date only? If not, you may want to build one with truncated value (by day, or hour), and use int datatype, which will make the index much smaller for faster query.

---

Or, another way to optimize (golden rule #1 don't do it, #2 do't do it now).

If and only if your date and PK are sync in sequence, you can build a external index of Range of StartDate <=> ID (PK).

and using below pattern

```
SELECT @start:=ID_START FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE StartDate='2013-01-01'
SELECT @end:=ID_END     FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE StartDate='2013-12-31'
SELECT * FROM calls WHERE ID BETWEEN @start and @end AND CustId in (xxxxx) ....
```

By using above pattern, Mysql will know if has to scan only a segment of table.

Answer (score 3):

Like Darhazer said, you have way too many indexes, start by removing all of them and build them up again based on your needs.

For this specific query, create **one** INDEX with these fields in it:

```
DateStart
CallLength
Direction 
CustID
```

Change `AND Direction = '1'` to `AND Direction = 1` (remove the quotes, you're comparing an integer, not a string)

And see what this does to your query time. If this goes well, add the subquery, check it again with EXPLAIN, add the needed indexes and so on.

Comment: @Darhazer I understand it looks like alot of indexes, but we have probably 200+ queries which use the calls table, and they all search the table using different tables and therefore the majority of the indexes are being used.

Comment: I don't think the proposed composite index (starting with DateStart) is going to help much here.  The secondary fields in the index (CallLength, Direction, and CustID) will only come into play for records with identical values of DateStart, and won't help at all when searching for a range of DateStart values.

Comment: @jokeeffe I'd expect the highest-selectivity index to be the most useful to put first, to strip out as much data as early as possible (at least that's how some other systems work, I'm less familiar with MySQL).  Does MySQL work differently?

Answer (score 3):

The best index that your query should be hitting is `idx_CustID_DateStart`. The `IN` statement is preventing that from happening. If the `CustID` list is from a table, I suggest `JOIN` it in, instead of enumerating.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that the original query that takes more than 7 minutes, is written correctly when you are worried by a subquery which takes 5 seconds (hopefully it is not executed for each row). But anyway, if you want to speed up this one you should read something how indexes work. I would recommend [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/) to begin with.

Basically you have conditions on 4 fields, and on two fields those are range conditions. If you have read the article, you know that the index is effectively used until the first range condition is met. Though, the rest of the data in index can be used for index scanning.  Thus, you need to choose which condition is better narrowing the resultset: on `DateStart` or on `CallLength`.

Anyway, you need a composite index that starts with `(CustID, Direction ...`. My feeling is that a condition on the DateStart is better. So I would start with `(CustID, Direction, DateStart, CallLength)`, and compare it with `(CustID, Direction, DateStart)`, because the last field might not give a sufficient performance gain, but will take memory resources.

Though I still think, one should be sure that the rest of the query is written correctly when concentrating on a subquery. There might be a properer way to organize the query, so that this optimization would turn out irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

4.5s is not much for a 1.6m rows returned, I am pretty sure it's all spent on IO operations. Then there is hardly any space left for optimisation. You'd better present us your original query, may be we can help better.

What % of total those 1.6m makes? Indexes are good if they're used to return smallest part of dataset, but since their [data access pattern with mrr is random reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mrr-optimization.html), its sometimes more efficient using fullscan on a table. Surely it depends on how data has been added to the table and how space was allocated on disk.

Also you might find useful to monitor performance with MySQL [performance schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html), look [here](http://www.markleith.co.uk/2011/04/18/monitoring-table-and-index-io-with-performance_schema/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You have too much indexes. For example, you don't need a separate CustID Index, becuase it's the left-most in the CustID,DateStart. You have 2 indexes on UnansweredFlag. And do you really need all of those indexes? This not only slows down the inserts/updates, it also slows down the optimzier and may trick the optimizer to choose not-so-good index.

Now, on the specific query. You need to see what field or combination limits the query the most (as now it scans  1,6M rows!) and force it to use that index. So run SELECT COUNT(*) queries for each of the where clauses (direction, call length) with the DateStart specified (you'll always want to limit based on this). Maybe you just need to add the direction to the index.

Also, before MySQL 5.6, subqueries in the WHERE clause are not optimized, so maybe you should rewrite the entire query to use join instead of subselect, and not to optimize the particular query

Comment: '(as now it scans 1,6M rows!)' - That's actually the amount of rows it would return (1.6m)

Comment: Also, the subquery isn't used in the where statement - just as a join.
E.g.
`LEFT JOIN ( SELECT * FROM x ) ON x.a = y.a`

Comment: @Stanyer try adding Direction and CallLength to the index to remove the `Using where` part.

Comment: is there any point in adding Direction to an index when the cardinality is so low? (2, on a table with around 30m rows).
From what I understand low cardinality columns perform better without being indexed?